# How do i teleport a Specified Item to coords?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a Tri-Dimensional "duper" for dragon eggs, and they get sent through the end and back to the overworld. A repeating command block at spawn then teleports `@e[type=item] to ~ ~1 ~` where a hopper awaits above the command block to send the eggs to a large chest storage system, the problem?

It teleports ANY item. Is there any way to specify which item to teleport? I want specifically only dragon eggs to teleport above the command block.

EDIT: Not a dupe of [How to test for a dropped item in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341826/how-to-test-for-a-dropped-item-in-minecraft)

Reason: They are asking for the equal of /testfor or /execute. I simply wished to teleport an item. Different Questions. Also, this dupe was marked nearly 5/6 months after the question was answered.

People please read the contents of a post before marking it as a duplicate, and also read the date.

Comment: You'll find the answer with only a little more research.  You can list additional selectors in your arguments.  Maybe one of these might help? https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selector_arguments

Comment: @Slurpee Nope, I thought of trying @e[type=item,id=dragon_egg] or @e[type=item,name=dragon_egg] but both didnt work

Comment: For now Ill have to work with x,y,z and distance detecting...

Comment: Hmmmmm I also tried @e[type=item,nbt={id="dragon_egg"}] but that didnt seem to cut it either... sadface

Comment: You need to check for the NBT, there is no "id" selector argument.

Comment: Do you guys even know the Answer?!?! your telling me that the stuff is wrong yet your not answering my question...

Comment: @pppery Why are you opening a question that was already answered (And is more than 5 months old). I already got enough downvotes as is, stop ruining shet even more :L

The question you attached as duplicate is for the command /execute, NOT /teleport.

Please read the post's contents before marking as a dupe. Read the edit to the post for more info

Comment: The age of a question is entirely irrelevant when deciding whether a question should be closed as duplicate. Nor are immaterial differences like which command the target selector belongs to. Both questions can be easily distilled into "how do I write a target selector that selects a certain type of item?", and so both are duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by a friend:

> For 1.13/1.14, you can filter by item ID:
>
> /teleport @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:dragon_egg"}}] ~ ~1 ~